# Android 13 - Permission to access PDF or other type of files

Tags: java, android, storage, android-permissions, file-permissions

As required, for apps targeting Android 13+ I'm using the following permission requests for the media files:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

The problem that I have is that this permissions doesn't seem to be enough to access other type of files such as pdfs, stickers etc that are saved in the storage.
When I want to access such files it will through a `FileNotFoundException` due to lack of proper permissions.

For example:

```
File file = new File(<path_to_File>);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file); // Here it will through the exception
```

For other type of files it works just fine.

Any solution for that?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use SAF and for exemple ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user pick the file.

No permissions needed at all.

Comment: Well the problem is that for this use case I don't want the user to pick the file. The app should read the PDF files created by other apps and show them within the app without the user selecting the files. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Yes and no. If you implement MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE you can do without user interaction. But to enable all files access you still need user interaction. And play store will not accept your app.